# How to push all the objects inside an array

Tags: javascript

It will give data by checking for each `variant` inside the variant array, it show all the object if the condition matched or undefined if not, but in this particular code, it is creating a new array for each item, something like this :-
`[{id: 'something'}] [{id: 'something'}] [{id: 'something'}] [{id: 'something'}]`
I want it to have all the result inside one array:-

```js
[
  {id: 'something'},
  {id: 'something'},
  {id: 'something'},
  {id: 'something'}
]
```

```js
const mynewarr = [];
const myimages = product_details.data.product.images;
      
      for(var i = 0; i < product_details.data.product.variants.length; i++) {
        const myvari = product_details.data.product.variants[i].image_id;
        const real = myimages.find(imageid => imageid.id == myvari);
        mynewarr.push(real);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post what the `myimages` array looks like? And also the variants array.

Comment: Can you please add the input data and what result is expected ?

Comment: I want the final data to be pushed inside an array or to show all the data inside that for loop to be inside an array

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni, I have updated the code

Comment: Use: `mynewarr.push(...real)`

Comment: The posted code will produce an array of arrays only if myimages contains arrays and those arrays have id props.  Unlikely.

Comment: I meant if you could add a sample array of `myimages` and `variants` array? The `myimages` array is likely to be an array of arrays.

Comment: yes its an array of array

Comment: Please explain how those arrays came to have id props.  The find predicate asks each member of the array (which are themselves arrays) for their `id` prop.  Did some unposted code assign an `id` prop to those arrays?  Doing so will work, but will confuse nearly every reader of that code (including those on SO)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a destructuring assignment to "unpack" the array before the push.

```
mynewarr.push(...real);
```

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to go:

```
const newArray = product_details.data.product.variants.map((variant) => variant.image_id === 'your_condition' ? { id: variant.image_id } : undefined)
```

The `newArray` will contain an array of objects with the ids.

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `myimages` is an array of array, you can push the object by accessing the 0th index of the filtered item(using `.find`).
If there's a possibility that the `.find` method might return `undefined` you can add a conditional check to push only the found items.
You can update your code to something like the below.

```
      const mynewarr = [];
      const myimages = product_details.data.product.images;
      
      for(var i = 0; i < product_details.data.product.variants.length; i++){
        const myvari = product_details.data.product.variants[i].image_id;
        const real = myimages.find(imageid => imageid.id === myvari) 
        if(real){
         mynewarr.push(real[0]); //Add only the object and not the sub array.
       }
      }
```

Comment: What is the meaning of real[0], I don't want to add the first one, I want to add for each item each find object returned

Comment: Since you mentioned that `myimages` are an array of array, I assume the data structure to be something like `[{id:'something'}]`, so instead of pushing the array you'd want to get only the object by accessing the 0th element that is the object with the attribute `id`.

Comment: no sorry, its not an array of array